# How to add 1 month to selected DateTimePicker

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker

I'm having an issue with DateTimePicker.

What I am currently trying to do is based off of what text is in lblPrevSem(Previous Semester), which is getting its selection from a drop down on a previous screen, i want to add a certain amount of time to the DateTimePicker.

```
Public Property CustomFormat As String
Dim SemesterMonths As Integer
Dim SemesterDays As Integer


Private Sub DeptCreatePrevSch_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim SemesterYear() As String = DeptPrevSch.CboSem.Text.Split(",")


    lblPrevSem.Text = SemesterYear(0)
    cboYear.Text = Date.Now.Year
    For i As Integer = 0 To 5
        cboYear.Items.Add(Date.Now.Year + i)
        cboYear.SelectedIndex = 0
    Next

    If InStr(lblPrevSem.Text, "Fall") Then
        SemesterMonths = 1
    ElseIf InStr(lblPrevSem.Text, "Spring") Then
        SemesterMonths = 1
    ElseIf InStr(lblPrevSem.Text, "Summer") Then
        SemesterDays = 14
    End If

    Call dtpStart_ValueChanged(sender, e)
End Sub

Private Sub dtpStart_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dtpStart.ValueChanged

    Dim StartDate As Date
    Dim StartStringDate As String
    Dim EndDate As Date
    Dim EndStringDate As String


    dtpStart.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
    dtpStart.CustomFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy  dddd"

    StartDate = dtpStart.Value.ToString
    StartStringDate = StartDate.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy  dddd")
    lblRegStartDate.Text = StartStringDate

    EndDate = dtpStart.Value.AddMonths(SemesterMonths)
    EndDate = dtpStart.Value.AddDays(SemesterDays)
    EndStringDate = EndDate.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy  dddd")
    lblRegEndDate.Text = EndStringDate

End Sub
```

I can get it to add in days just fine but when ever i try and add in 1 month, it doesn't seem to work at all.

I've tried multiple different ways to add in a 1 month but nothing so far has worked. The closet ive been was adding in 30 days but then that doesn't account for months that have 31 days.

**Reg Start Date** is what ever the DateTimePicker is and **Reg End Date** should be the added days based off of what lblPrevSem is

Both Reg Start/End Date are displayed as labels

(i.e. Fall = 1 Month, Spring = 1 Month, Summer = 2 Weeks)

Comment: First it is a really bad idea to call an event that way, events are supposed to indicate user interaction.  Put the code in a method can call it from whereever.  `Dim StartDate As Date ... = dtpStart.Value.ToString` makes me think Option Strict is not on.  Some of those dtp properties could be set in the designer once rather than over and over in a method

Comment: i didnt know these could be set in the designer?

Comment: And i completely forgot to set option strict on. Well damn all that work and for nothing....back to work then i guess....thanks for reminding me about that.

Comment: I was talking about the Format and CustomFormat - they really do not need to be set each time the value changes.  You can set Option Strict on as a permanent default: Tools -> Projects & Solutions -> VB Defaults.  To set it for this project: Project Properties -> Compile tab/page

Comment: thanks for that tip. Luckily i just need to redo this form. A lot of work for nothing....hate that

Comment: in the mean time im going to go cry in a corner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are resetting the value for EndDate after adding the SemesterMonths value.  You should add the SemesterDays value to the EndDate variable, not reset the value of EndDate with dtpStart.Value.AddDays(SemesterDays):

```
EndDate = dtpStart.Value.AddMonths(SemesterMonths)
EndDate = EndDate.AddDays(SemesterDays)
```

Comment: thanks, ill look into that after i rewrite all this since i forgot to put option strict on like an idiot

Answer (score 1):

Just get the datetimepicker value and put .AddYears(0) or .AddDays(0) or AddMonths(0) behind it.
But you can also use them all at the same time.

```
nextServiceDateTimePicker.Value.AddYears(0).AddDays(0).AddMonths(0);
```

Just replace the 0 with lets say i and give it the value you need it to be.